# Simple python server similar to SimpleHTTPServer but with PHP support?

Tags: php, python, simplehttpserver

I use `python -m SimpleHTTPServer` when I want to run my web application locally, quickly and without much pain. However, `SimpleHTTPServer` lacks any PHP support (or even MySQL support).

Is there something similar I can do (preferably but not necessarily to do with Python) to get a quick PHP server up and running for testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[WPHP](http://pythonpaste.org/wphp/) will allow you to run PHP in a WSGI container, of which there are several standalone.