# Localhost server with php and ssl

Tags: php

I'm searching for the server which allows to launch php files with ssl. I've tried for example python simple server:

```
import BaseHTTPServer, SimpleHTTPServer
import ssl

httpd = BaseHTTPServer.HTTPServer(('127.0.0.1', 4443), SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler)
httpd.socket = ssl.wrap_socket (httpd.socket, keyfile='privkeyA.pem', certfile='certA.crt', server_side=True)
print("Server is working!")
httpd.serve_forever()
```

Certificate and key works well, but I can only launch html files, because this server doesn't support php ones.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12235876/python-simplehttpserver-with-php

Comment: I would recommend to use the standard xAMP stack for PHP. e.g. [WAMP](https://sourceforge.net/projects/wampserver/) for Windows. To enable SSL you then can use [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/), which will give you an external HTTPS URL that is redirected to your `localhost`. That is what I am using and it works.

Comment: Anything that has Apache or Nginx! `WAMPServer` or `XAMPP` or there are a few other

Comment: Of course we are assuming you are a windows user

Answer (score 3):

Use can use [Php Build in Server](http://php.net/manual/en/features.commandline.webserver.php) + [ngrok](https://ngrok.com) for getting Https+SSL

Comment: so far, the easiest and fastest way to get it done

Comment: @dsncode How did you implement ngrok on PHP built in webserver? thanks.

Comment: @Isabella just create your server and enable ngrok in your development server. then expose your app port through ngrok. then you got free dynamic url and ssl endpoint.
you can follow the instructions on ngrok website https://ngrok.com/docs

Answer (score 1):

im using laragon now, its built-in ssl , and they support cool things
https://laragon.org/download/index.html

Note : windows

Comment: it's really fast and easy to setup.  There will be a little confusion when you find a port conflict, but solving it is a piece of cake, just go to setting above it.

Comment: But how you would debug with laragon?