# Facebook Login Button (ON LOCALHOST.) : The Login Button plugin no longer works on http pages

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Okay, so I have this app that needs to access the FB api in order to post content... thing is, I'm, of course, trying my app on localhost. (php5.6 internal server)

I keep getting the error:

```
The Login Button plugin no longer works on http pages. Please update your site to use https for Facebook Login.
```

and

```
The method FB.getLoginStatus can no longer be called from http pages.
```

despite the fact that people keep saying that https is not required for localhost, so long as the app is in development, which it is.

I thought maybe it was because I was running the php server on port 8000, but I checked using `php5.6 -S localhost:80` just in case and the result is literally the same.

The code is:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<div class="fb-login-button" data-width="" data-size="large" data-button-type="continue_with" data-auto-logout-link="false" data-use-continue-as="true"></div>


<script>
  function statusChangeCallback(response) {  // Called with the results from FB.getLoginStatus().
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);                   // The current login status of the person.
    if (response.status === 'connected') {   // Logged into your webpage and Facebook.
      testAPI();
    } else {                                 // Not logged into your webpage or we are unable to tell.
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' +
        'into this webpage.';
    }
  }


  function checkLoginState() {               // Called when a person is finished with the Login Button.
    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // See the onlogin handler
      statusChangeCallback(response);
    });
  }


  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : '[totally valid id belonging to my development app I quadruple checked.]',
      cookie     : true,                     // Enable cookies to allow the server to access the session.
      xfbml      : true,                     // Parse social plugins on this webpage.
      version    : 'v5.0'           // Use this Graph API version for this call.
    });


    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {   // Called after the JS SDK has been initialized.
      statusChangeCallback(response);        // Returns the login status.
    });
  };


  (function(d, s, id) {                      // Load the SDK asynchronously
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
    js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
  }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));


  function testAPI() {                      // Testing Graph API after login.  See statusChangeCallback() for when this call is made.
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function(response) {
      console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
      document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
        'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
  }
</script>


<div id="status">
</div>
```

Please, help me out here. Do I really have to set up a server with https etc etc just for this?

Comment: not sure how it works with php, but with node.js you can use a tool called "devcert" to have https on localhost. i am sure there is something for php too. btw, php 5.x is outdated, you should really update to 7.x already.

Comment: I can't do that. It would take too much of my precious time that my client is unwilling to pay. Btw thanks for the tip, I just started using apache + an mkcert certificate. Sucks a bit, is unnecessarily complicated... but I'm finally able to move on. Thank you. Post a response, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With node.js you can use a tool called "devcert" to have https on localhost.

For PHP:

- [How do I allow HTTPS for Apache on localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4221874/how-do-i-allow-https-for-apache-on-localhost)
- [Localhost server with php and ssl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53322705/localhost-server-with-php-and-ssl)
- https://linoxide.com/linux-how-to/mkcert-localhost-ssl-certificates-linux/

Answer (score 0):

following change works for me without any issue

change localhost URL from
'localhost/yoursitename' to  'https://localhost/yoursitename'